# What to do for setting host configuration in elastic search to connect cluster nodes in php?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, composer-php

Elastic search has been installed successfully, using composer.json by

```
{
    "require": {
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~2.0",
        "monolog/monolog": "~1.0"
    }
}
```

and configure it with

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();
//at this time hosts=['localhost:9200'] is default one
//but apache is running in port no 80,
```

and there is error like

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException' with message 
'No alive nodes found in your cluster' in 
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/elasticsearch/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/ConnectionPool/StaticNoPingConnectionPool.php:51
```

and I tried another settings

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts('127.0.0:80')->build();
```

which gives the error of bad request

What should I do right here, I think I need some other server that runs on port number 9200, and store the cluster nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component that you required in your composer file, is just the php interface to talk to Elastic search.

Elastic search itself needs to be installed separately on the web-server (or another server) as well. That is unrelated to php / composer. Note that you probably need root access to your server to do that.

Here you can find what you need: https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, '127.0.0:80' is not correct, should be 127.0.0.1:80